# How can I make this command by using ffmpeg-python?

Tags: ffmpeg, ffmpeg-python

```
ffmpeg -i brooklynsfinest_clip_1080p.mp4 \
-filter_complex \
"[0:v]split=3[v1][v2][v3]; \
[v1]copy[v1out]; [v2]scale=w=1280:h=720[v2out]; [v3]scale=w=640:h=360[v3out]" \
-map [v1out] -c:v:0 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:0 5M -maxrate:v:0 5M -minrate:v:0 5M -bufsize:v:0 10M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map [v2out] -c:v:1 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:1 3M -maxrate:v:1 3M -minrate:v:1 3M -bufsize:v:1 3M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map [v3out] -c:v:2 libx264 -x264-params "nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1" -b:v:2 1M -maxrate:v:2 1M -minrate:v:2 1M -bufsize:v:2 1M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 \
-map a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k -ac 2 \
-map a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 96k -ac 2 \
-map a:0 -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 48k -ac 2 \
-f hls \
-hls_time 2 \
-hls_playlist_type vod \
-hls_flags independent_segments \
-hls_segment_type mpegts \
-hls_segment_filename stream_%v/data%02d.ts \
-master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
-var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1 v:2,a:2" stream_%v.m3u8
```

how can I convert this command to ffmpeg-python code?
I don't know how to do this

Comment: is this converting the input mp4 file? I'm not sure exactly what this command is doing

Answer (score 0):

Use subprocess.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("ffmpeg", "next arg", "next arg")
```

Remember to `import subprocess`.